# How to retrieve person names from DBPedia in different language versions?

Tags: r, sparql, dbpedia

I am currently querying DBPedia for a list of person names by using the SPARQL package in R. I noticed that when I use SPARQL query for **English** DBPedia like this：

```
   endpoint = "http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql"
   query= "SELECT *{
   dbpedia:Veit_Dietrich ?p ?o 
   }"
   qd=SPARQL(endpoint,query)
   df=qd$results
```

Everything is fine, but if I want to query **German** DBPedia and change the **endpoint**, something turns out wrong:

```
   endpoint = "http://de.dbpedia.org/sparql"
   query= "SELECT *{
   dbpedia:Veit_Dietrich ?p ?o 
   }"
   qd=SPARQL(endpoint,query)
   df=qd$results
```

I think the problem might be related with *"dbpedia:Veit_Dietrich"*, but I don't know how to modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [namespaces](http://uk.dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl) of dbpeida in different languages are different. Thus you need to change your namespace:

```
SELECT *{
    dbpedia-de:Veit_Dietrich ?p ?o 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a namespace problem. In the german DBpedia endpoint you have to use the namespace http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/ . And it seems that the prefix dbpedia ist still reserved for the common http://dbpedia.org/resource/ namespace.

Try

```
select * where {<http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Veit_Dietrich> ?p ?o}
```